# Surjections between homology groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

When does there exist a continuous surjection between two cell complexes $X$ and $Y$ such that $H_*(X)$ is not isomorphic to $H_*(Y)$. What properties must be satisfied?

Comment: What's a surjection in "different homology groups"?

Comment: I want a surjection between two cell complexes. Not between the sets of cell complexes.

Comment: Oh, wait.  Do you want a surjective map $f: X \to Y$ of cell complexes where $H_*(X)$ is not isomorphic to $H_*(Y)$?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I want.

Comment: Examples are everywhere.   Take the standard double cover $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$.  This is a covering map, so surjective.  In $H_1$ we have the trivial group versus $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  I don't know how you would get conditions/properties for this.

Comment: I don't think there can be a surjection from a sphere to a torus. When does that restriction happen in general.

Comment: @Halbort: Hint: For every connected compact CW complex $X$ there is a continuous surjection $[0,1]\to X$.

Comment: Every map $S^2 \to T^2$ induced the zero map on $H_2$ (one argues using covering space theory or cohomology rings). Perhaps this is what you're thinking of.

Comment: You could take the continuous surjection where $X$ is anything and $Y$ is a point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually somewhat rare for there to *not* exist a continuous surjection between two arbitrary CW-complexes, and the only real obstructions are connectedness and compactness, not with homology as you seem to think.  In particular, for instance, if $Y$ is any finite connected CW-complex, then there exists a continuous surjection $[0,1]\to Y$ by the [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem).  It follows that if $X$ is any CW-complex of positive dimension, there exists a continuous surjection $X\to Y$ (since we can compose with a continuous surjection $X\to [0,1]$).

It follows easily, for instance, that if $X$ and $Y$ are both finite CW-complexes, there exists a continuous surjection $X\to Y$ iff $X$ has at least as many connected components as $Y$ and $X$ has at least as many non-singleton connected components as $Y$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you explain why there is no surjection between the sphere and the torus.

Comment: There is a continuous surjection from the sphere to the torus, since they are both finite connected CW-complexes of positive dimension.

Comment: Ok, I must have misheard someone then.